# Unknown php file path in a login form

Tags: php

When I saw the `html` code of login page a site, I saw the following `url` in part of the `action` feature.While when I learn about creating a form in internet, in the examples be used `phpfilename` with the `.php` and it is 
incompatible with the tutorials that are in internet.

```
<form class="form-horizontal "
  dir="rtl"
  action="/login/?next=/account/?l=fa" method="post">
    ...........
    ..........
         </form>
```

Comment: You should read a bit about "clean urls" and "rewriting rules".

Comment: (which does not cover the fact that that url is a bit, well, amateurish...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not always that the form action will be a .php, .asp or any server side side language. But this doesn't mean that the form is not processed by those server side languages, it's just that sometimes we rewrite the URL's in the .htaccess file, a file used to grant access to certain directories in webapps and also has the ability to redirect users from unknown or denied directories to usually the index page, to produce neat or let me say attractive URL's.

This is usually done in Single Page Applications (SPA) usually built with the MVC (Model View Controller) or MVVC (Model View ViewController).

The .htaccess provides the ability to write neat and attractive URL's. Behind the scenes it takes this so called neat URL and then explode it to find the .php or the server side language's file needed to process the form. This is usually called Controller in MVC apps.

Answer (score 0):

As you are the very beginner in using php form so try to put the action field blank

```
<form class="form-horizontal" dir="rtl" action="" method="post">
```

Or something like this,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" dir="rtl" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using post method to send data. So any of data not show in url.

So in your form action  `action="/login/?next=/account/?l=fa"` you cnt use like this. Just give a page path like

```
action='login.php'
```

So in `login.php`, you can  cathe the variables using `$_POST`.

```
$name = $_POST['name']//form input field name
```